# Is it ok to perform a full collection scan on a low volume firestore collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, database-performance

My mobile application's backend is a few small firebase/google cloud functions which perform various CRUD operations on my firestore database. I have come into the issue where I require to update all documents in a collection daily. I have a cron job which triggers the function every day at a specified time. To avoid doing a full collection scan, I tried a few hacky ways to get around not being able to self invoke functions like with AWS lambdas. Ultimately these did not work. As I am not expecting high volumes of data (each document up to around 8 string fields; expecting a max of 10,000 documents) I was thinking maybe a full collection scan wouldn't actually be that expensive. Has anyone had experience with full table scans on firestore, and what was the performance like?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What is a full collection scan? What are you trying to do exactly? What performance are we talking about?

Comment: Get all documents in a collection. I am trying to get all documents in a collection from a cloud function and then loop through and update a field. Just wondering is this OK to do from a Google cloud function in terms of speed. Wondering if I will potentially come into time out issues and things like that?

Comment: why do you have to scan if you have to update all documents anyway? Sounds like a weird design. Maybe you can explain why this is needed?

Comment: Well I need to get the id of the item to be able to update it with correct value. I can't update the document if I don't know which it is. So basically I have an expiration status field and I need this to be updated dialy as the value of it is based on the date. If that makes sense. Not every record needs updating but it may do which is why I need to get each document to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an expiration status field and I need this to be updated [daily] as the value of it is based on the date.

Instead of scanning the entire collection every day, consider using Cloud Task to trigger each individual document exactly when it expires. This is likely to be more efficient over time as it scales with the number of expiring documents, rather than with the total number of documents. For an example of triggering individual documents through Cloud Tasks, see Doug's blog post: [How to schedule a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks (to build a Firestore document TTL)](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

---

Even if you keep doing this task as you're doing it now, you shouldn't need to do a full table scan. Rather you should be able to [use a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) based on the current date and the field in the documents that determines whether they are expired. This means you're loading a subset of the data.

Finally, if the number of documents you'll need to process will continue to grow, implement [cursor based pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) so that you process the total number of documents in batches - and don't run out of memory as the number of document grows.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I could see  how that could work. Expanding on your last point how would I go about creating a cloud function to process batches and then self trigger to query the next batch? I have looked at docs but haven't been able to see a way of doing it with cloud functions or is there no way of doing this

Comment: To prevent memory problems just pagination is enough, and self-triggering isn't needed. If you want to perform the work through multiple Cloud Function invocations, you could for example lt the original Function post a message to pubsub for each page.

Comment: OK that sounds a robust solution. So I could have a function which reads a page from the dB sends it to a pub sub and have an update function which triggers when a message gets to the topic. Do I need to do anything special to limit a function to only read one message from the topic? And I am guessing it would scale automatically and spin up another function if another message got on the topic and the function was already processing a message? Apologies if these are simple questions I come mainly from an aws background only just moved over to Google cloud

Comment: I'd recommend to first try getting this working with just a single Cloud Function that paginates over the results. Once you have that working you'll have a better idea how many documents you can chance in a single Function's maximum execution time, and thus be in a better place to decide whether spreading it through PubSub is needed.